# Code completion for C code in TensorFlow

Tags: c, emacs, tensorflow, atom-editor

I am developing a custom Op for TensorFlow, using Ubuntu on virtual machine and either rmate to edit the code in local Atom installation on my Mac, or Emacs to edit it right on the virtual machine.

Is there a way to enable code completion suggestions for C code in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1):

There's no special support in TensorFlow for code completion, but there may be a specific solution for your editor. For example, [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/528407) covers different approaches to C/C++ code completion in Emacs.

One way I've managed to get C++ auto-completion is to use the (experimental) [TensorFlow CMake build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake) to generate Visual Studio project files for the project, and then use Visual Studio to edit the code.

Comment: I've set up Atom to support code completion for C and C++ already, it just doesn't work with TensorFlow. But thanks for pointing at the TensorFlow CMake build, I will check it out!